# Change CSS Link Visited Hover active in html section

Tags: html, css, web, stylesheet

I want to do a dynamic word cloud and I was wondering if there is a way of changing the link colour in my html section, normally you just define the links colours in css something like:

```
.tag_cloud { padding: 3px; text-decoration: none; }
.tag_cloud:link  { color: #0c3569; }
.tag_cloud:visited { color: #0c3569; }
.tag_cloud:hover { color: #ffffff; background: #0c3569; }
.tag_cloud:active { color: #ffffff; background: #0c3569; }
```

But I'm planning to do a word cloud were every word has a different colour, aka link/visited will colour will be defined dinamicaly, but is there a way of defining link/visited/hover/active inline in the html?

I Imagine it could be something like this

```
<a href="something" style="font:arial; ???"word</a>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can't be done inline since :hover etc. are css pseudo selectors and won't work inline since that is not the intention of it.

But don't be afraid of using css classes - you will need some javascript anyway to make this work. Just define the classes you want to use like:

```
.cloud_item_1:link {color:red;}
.cloud_item_1:visited {color:yellow;}
.cloud_item_1:hover {text-decoration:underline;}
.cloud_item_1:active {color:black;}
.cloud_item_2:link {color:blue;}
.cloud_item_2:visited {color:orange;}
...
```

And than apply them to your html as you wish. No big deal here.

Comment: your code is very good, but dont know why said that he would need js to make this work, he don't.
He can as well render the style in <style> tags in the page header of his html file and achieve the desired result.

Comment: Well, I have 250 words in my cloud so I'm going to need to create a css file of 4x240=1000 lines . Eck :-/

Comment: I just hope you're gonna use some generator for it :) Hand picking all this colors would be a deadly task - maybe this can help you atleast a bit http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 0):

You would need to have some JavaScript to change the color on hover and check if the item is active.

Or you could define a class/id (dynamically) for each of the items and target them with CSS.